# Ignore certificate check while fetching kickstart file that is located in an un-trusted location

Tags: linux, system-installation, ssl, certificates, kickstart

I have been using kickstart file that is located in remote (in an untrusted location). I want to fetch the kickstart file while booting the OS for automated installation.

I used to mention my kickstart file as follows

```
ks=https://<url>
```

I know that, in wget we can ignore the certificate check by using **--no-check-certificate** option.

Is there any similar way to ignore this certificate check in kickstart?